# Using multiple vectors and conditional logic to create a new vector

Tags: r, conditional-statements, lubridate

I've been struggling and searching for hours find a way of creating a new vector t2 based on the content of three other vectors odate, ddate, and rdate and two dates.  I'm no expert at R and it may not be pretty, but I've got most of it to work, except the two lines which I've indicated with #warning.  I suspect that this isn't the right way to do this, but it's the only way I can think of.  I tried using ifelse, but it strips out the date formatting which I need.  Any pointers gratefully recieved.

```
library(lubridate)

odate = ymd(c("2005-09-26",
          "2005-09-22",
          "2005-09-15",
          "2005-03-10",
          "2004-12-09",
          "2003-11-17",
          "2003-06-08",
          "2005-02-01",
          "2009-10-04",
          "2003-11-20",
          "2004-03-15"))

ddate = ymd(c("2010-08-16",
          "NA",
          "2006-12-18",
          "NA",
          "NA",
          "2004-04-22",
          "NA",
          "NA",
          "NA",
          "2010-10-07",
          "2005-07-07"))

rdate = ymd(c("2005-11-07",
          "2006-05-11",
          "NA",
          "2006-04-28",
          "2005-01-06",
          "NA",
          "NA",
          "NA",
          "NA",
          "NA",
          "NA"))

start.year = ymd("2005-01-01")

end.year = ymd("2005-12-31")

t2 = pmin(rdate, ddate, end.year)

t2[is.na(ddate) & !is.na(rdate) & rdate <= end.year] = rdate # warning

t2[is.na(ddate) & !is.na(rdate) & rdate > end.year] = end.year 

t2[is.na(rdate) & !is.na(ddate) & ddate <= end.year] = ddate # warning

t2[is.na(rdate) & !is.na(ddate) & ddate > end.year] = end.year 

t2[is.na(rdate) & is.na(ddate)]  = end.year

t2[odate > end.year | (!is.na(rdate) & rdate < start.year) | (!is.na(ddate) & ddate < start.year)] = ymd("1970-01-01")

t2

[1] "2005-11-07 UTC" "2005-12-31 UTC" "2005-12-31 UTC" "2005-12-31 UTC" "2005-11-07 UTC" "1970-01-01 UTC" "2005-12-31 UTC"
[8] "2005-12-31 UTC" "1970-01-01 UTC" "2005-12-31 UTC" NA
```

`t2` should be:

```
"2005-11-07 UTC" "2005-12-31 UTC" "2005-12-31 UTC" "2005-12-31 UTC" "2005-01-06 UTC" "1970-01-01 UTC" "2005-12-31 UTC"
"2005-12-31 UTC" "1970-01-01 UTC" "2005-12-31 UTC" "2005-07-07 UTC"
```

I’ll try to explain in words.

By creating t2 as the minimum of the three dates, odate, rdate and ddate, and as all three date vectors always have the same length, t2 will have the same length as the three dates.

The two lines that give the warnings are the next part of the structure of the vector.  If there is no ddate, but there is an rdate and it’s less than the end date, this rdate should be the value for this position in the vector t2.  Similarly, if there is no rdate, but there is a ddate and it’s less than the end date, ddate should be the value for the position in the vector.

The three lines that make t2 equal to the end.date under various conditions all work fine.

Finally, the last line “zeroes” the dates if they fall outside the start and end dates, overriding any previous values if necessary.

The logic vector created by “is.na(ddate) & !is.na(rdate) & rdate <= end.year“ has 11 elements as do the rdate and ddate vectors, so what I thought would happen is that when the logic was true, the value from this index in rdate would be taken by t2, but clearly not.

Comment: note: when you subset on the lhs, you also need to do this on the rhs of the assignment *if it is a vector of the same length). ie `t2[condition] <- rdate[condition]`

Comment: @ user20650 I don’t know what logic I could apply to the rhs or rdate.  Can you elaborate?

Comment: as @user20650 points, the problem is that you subset t2, but not rdate/ddate. The logical vector `is.na(ddate) & !is.na(rdate) & rdate <= end.year` has 11 elements, but the length of `t2[is.na(ddate) & !is.na(rdate) & rdate <= end.year]` is equal to the number of `TRUE ` values of that logical vector (which is less than 11). However, `rdate` still has 11 elements. Therefore, `t2[is.na(ddate) & !is.na(rdate) & rdate <= end.year] = rdate[is.na(ddate) & !is.na(rdate) & rdate <= end.year]` should work

Comment: Thank you, that works perfectly.  I would never have realised that, although I can see why now.